# Is thera a way to use increment and decrement operators directly inside the print statement in python like we do in c

Tags: python, printing, python-3.6, increment, f-string

Example in C programming:

```c
int a=5;
printf("a : %d",++a);
```

In Python even if I use f - string i can't able to use it directly!

```py
print(f'a : {++a}')
```

it's not working

Comment: `a += 1; print(f'a: {a}')`

Comment: There are no increment/decrement operators in Python. The ``print`` *function* has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Python does not have either pre-increment or post-increment (or decrement for that matter) operators. All you're writing is `+(+(a))`, which is generally a no-op, twice.

Comment: Actually, starting from python 3.8 you can do `print("a : {}".format(a := a + 1))` or `print("a :", a := a + 1)`

Comment: @rdas so we have to use one more line !Is there any another way to increment it inside the print statement itself..

Comment: @OlvinRoght You're an amazing person Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, kind of, using an assignment expression (`:=`):

```
print(a := a + 1)
```

I wouldn't do this though. It needlessly convolutes your code. Just have a separate `a += 1` line for the sake of clarity.

Though, this only works in Python 3.8+. If you're on an earlier version of Python, no, there is no way of doing this outside of a creative hack like:

```
print((exec("a += 1"), a)[1])  # DEFINATELY DO NOT USE THIS!
```

`:=` is the only sane way to reassign a variable in a context that expects an expression.